# Two argument constructor to specify where the object should be drawn?

Tags: java, constructor

How would i make this into a two argument constructor that can be used to specify where to draw the object and/or scale the object.This is being used for a Jframe graphics project. I can post the Jframe too if it will help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;

/*
   component that draws the concert speakers
*/


public class ConcertSpeaker extends JComponent
{  
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {  

        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Recover Graphics2D 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

         // Speaker base
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Rectangle base = new Rectangle (300, 400, 50, 100);
        g2.fill(base);

        // Speakers circles gray top
        g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        Ellipse2D.Double speakerTop = new Ellipse2D.Double(310, 410, 30, 30); 
        g2.fill(speakerTop); 

        //speakers circles black top
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Ellipse2D.Double speakerTop1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(315, 415, 20, 20); 
        g2.fill(speakerTop1); 

        // Speakers circles gray bottom
        g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        Ellipse2D.Double speakerBottom = new Ellipse2D.Double(310, 450, 30, 30); 
        g2.fill(speakerBottom); 

        //speakers circles black bottom
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Ellipse2D.Double speakerBottom1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(315, 455, 20, 20); 
        g2.fill(speakerBottom1); 


    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think it could be done? Any ideas? Any thoughts about what the two arguments to the constructor would be? Any attempts at trying to make one?

Comment: there is no scaling in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure having a big component is the best thing to do but here is how you achieve what I understood you're asking (just the body of the class):

```
private int x, y;
private float scale;

public PosSCale(int x, int y, float scale) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.scale = scale;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{  

    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Recover Graphics2D 
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.translate(x, y);
    g2.scale(scale, scale);

     // Speaker base
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Rectangle base = new Rectangle (0, 0, 50, 100);
    g2.fill(base);

    // Speakers circles gray top
    g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    Ellipse2D.Double speakerTop = new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 30, 30); 
    g2.fill(speakerTop); 

    //speakers circles black top
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Ellipse2D.Double speakerTop1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(15, 15, 20, 20); 
    g2.fill(speakerTop1); 

    // Speakers circles gray bottom
    g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    Ellipse2D.Double speakerBottom = new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 50, 30, 30); 
    g2.fill(speakerBottom); 

    //speakers circles black bottom
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Ellipse2D.Double speakerBottom1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(15, 55, 20, 20); 
    g2.fill(speakerBottom1); 


}
```